# ¿Cómo usar listas o arreglos globales o cómo capturar los valores que me dió una función?

Tags: python-3.7

Tengo valores que guardo en listas que necesito seguir usando en otras funciones, entonces quisiera saber cómo puedo llamar a los valores de una función en otra, o cómo usar esas listas como variables globales, intenté este código de prueba antes de implementarlo en mi programa pero no me funcionó:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []

def prueba(): 
    global a
    global b
    global c
    global d
    cadena = ["1","2","3","4", "5"]
    a.append(cadena)
    print("pasando a a")
    b.append(cadena)
    print("pasando a b")
    c.append(cadena)
    print("pasando a c")
    d.append(cadena)
    print("pasando a d")
    return a, b, c, d


def segundamuestra():
    print("SegundaFuncion")
    prueba()
    print(a)

def terceramuestra():
    print("TerceraFuncion")
    prueba()
    print(b)

def cuartamuestra():
    print("cuartaFuncion")
    prueba()
    print(c)

def quintamuestra():
    print("quintafuncion")
    prueba()
    print(c)
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funcionó en tu código? ¿Qué esperabas obtener y qué obtuviste?

Answer (score 1):

Eso se consigue pasando el dato con el que quieras trabajar como parámetro de una función.

**Ejemplo 1:**

```
# Mis listas
a = ['Hola', 'Esto', 'Es', 'Una', 'Prueba']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


def muestra(lista):
    print(lista)


muestra(a) # Imprime => ['Hola', 'Esto', 'Es', 'Una', 'Prueba']
muestra(b) # Imprime => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**Ejemplo 2:**

```
numero = 11


def esPar(num):
    if (num % 2 == 0):
        print('Es un número par')
    else:
        print('No es un número par')


esPar(numero) # Imprime => No es un número par
```